# Missing Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hey i followed a ruby on rails guide when i tried to run it i got the following error and i don't know how to fix it:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#new

Showing /home/jandre/Downloads/RubyForRails/blog/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb where line #29 raised:

Missing partial tags/form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/jandre/Downloads/RubyForRails/blog/app/views"

Extracted source (around line #29):

26:   </div>
27:   <h2>Tags</h2>
28:    <%= render :partial => 'tags/form',
29:               :locals => {:form => f} %>
30:   <div class="actions">
31:     <%= f.submit %>
32:   </div>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/jandre/Downloads/RubyForRails/blog


app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:29:in `block in _app_views_posts__form_html_erb__1175061583764259658_69931731368600'
app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb__1175061583764259658_69931731368600'
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb___2345045124576917782_69931899129680'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:33:in `new'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that you don't have **_form** partial in **app/view/tags**

Comment: tnx Said Kaldybaev dude i saw i had a typo in the that file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your partial filename startes with an underscore:

`_somepartial.html.erb` rather than `somepartial.html.erb`